# legalpaper with newspaper package

Tags: geometry, paper-size, newspaper

Everything works fine and produces `legalpaper` document without `newspaper` package. However, when I use `\usepackage{newspaper}`, it is not rendering `legalpaper` document. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass[english,legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}


\usepackage{newspaper}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `newspaper.sty` explicitly sets the page parameters, so try to load it **before** geometry and say `\usepackage[paper=legalpaper]{geometry}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristianHupfer for your helpful comment. Would you like to change your comment to an answer. Thanks

Comment: JPi answered already, so it's no use to add a similar one.

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder, @ChristianHupfer.

Comment: @JPi: Nothing to worry -- your answer and my comment were posted at the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` business.  This works fine:

```
\documentclass[english,legalpaper]{article}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage[legalpaper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}




\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: And apparently the newspaper package sets the page sizes, so undoes anything you've done with `geometry.`  Switching the order of the two packages addresses the issue.